# Calling existing C code from C#

Tags: c#, c, dll

I am trying to call functions from a c library in c#. I received this library from a manufacturer of some hardware that is connected to my computer. I have read about using dlls to achieve this; However, all of the tutorials I have seen focus on linking some existing dll or a new dll solution to a c# solution.

I'm having trouble understanding how to go about generating the dll files from an existing c project. My current understanding is that I should create a new c dll project and add the classes that I am making calls to and simply make wrappers for them using pinvoke.

Is this a correct mindset? It seems like there should be more to this involving any dependencies and imports that these classes have. Is there a simpler solution that would just allow me to link one function?

To address the duplicate question: I am not asking how to link a c dll to c#, I am asking about the process of making the dll from a c solution that builds an exe. This is a step that I believe must be done before the solution linked.

Comment: so what exactly have you got form the vendor? c code, a .lib file?...

Comment: I have an actual sln that builds to an exe

Comment: I've voted to reopen your question.  I agree that it's not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: Does the solution build? You can P/Invoke an .exe the same way you can a .dll. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672792/calling-c-exe-functions-from-c-sharp

Comment: Yes it does, I will look into using this solution. Thanks!